# look for empty cell between non empty cells in one row and then put 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Anq.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Anq.png)
A    B    C
abc  30   40
def  4646

ghi   45  3234

So, I want to write a macro code where it takes all three columns into consideration at once.
for instance, if any of the three columns(A,B,C) has data like in row 2 but one cell is blank then it should add 0 there **BUT** if all cells of all columns are empty like in row 4 then it should ignore and keep it as it is.

Here, is what it should look like,
[enter image description here][2]

A    B    C
abc  30   40
0   def  4646

ghi   45  3234

Please, I would really appreciate the help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job described:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillEmptyCellsWithZero()
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oRange As Range, oRow As Range, aCells As Range, oCell As Range
Dim countEmptyCell As Integer
    Set oSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set oRange = Application.Intersect(oSheet.UsedRange, oSheet.Range("A:C"))
    For Each oRow In oRange.Rows
        countEmptyCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(oRow)
        If (countEmptyCell > 0) And (countEmptyCell < 3) Then
            Set aCells = oRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            For Each oCell In aCells.Cells
                oCell.Value = 0
            Next oCell
        End If
    Next oRow
End Sub
```

*But for some reason it seems to me that you will not be able to use it: the description of the task is clearly deliberately simplified and does not correspond to your real data - [**XY problem**](https://xyproblem.info/)*